# what is a python program to interchange first and last element of dictionary?

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, tuples

how may we interchange the positions of first and last element in a dictionary. I tried to use the swap function which did'nt work quite well for me, what can i use to achieve my desired result, please answer.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered. There is no “first” or “last”.

Comment: Did you mean to say "list"?

Comment: @Fastnlight Dictionaries have been guaranteed to maintain insertion order since 3.7. However, you can't insert at a specific position.

Comment: @Axe319 - Although you are technically correct, programming happiness is enhanced by assuming that dictionaries are unordered.  Especially for newbies, their life will be better by assuming that until they understand why it isn't true.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing this, I'm sure there is an easier way but this method should work

```
# Example dictionary
test_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}

# initializing swap indices (-1 represents the last element)
i, j = 0, -1

# conversion to tuples
tups = list(test_dict.items())

# swapping by indices
tups[i], tups[j] = tups[j], tups[i]

# converting back
res = dict(tups)
print(res)
```

This returns...

```
{'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) and its exclusive function `move_to_end()` which allows us to efficiently swap first and last elements of our dict:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dct = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
odct = OrderedDict({'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5})
odct.move_to_end(list(dct.keys())[0])
odct.move_to_end(list(dct.keys())[-1], last=False)
print(dct)
print(dict(odct))
```

Output:

```
{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
{'five': 5, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'one': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you meant to swap the sequence of the dictionary itself or just the values.

```
# dictionary value swap
test_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
test_dict['one'], test_dict['five']= test_dict['five'], test_dict['one']
print (test_dict)
Output:  {'one': 5, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 1}
```

You can also extract the first and last values (or any value) using keys.

```
test_dict = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
mylist = list(test_dict.keys())
mylist[0],mylist[-1]=mylist[-1],mylist[0]
print (mylist)
Output:  ['five', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'one']

result_1, result_2 = test_dict[mylist[0]], test_dict[mylist[-1]] 
print (result_1, "Key in list swapped ", result_2)
Output:  5 Key in list swapped 1

print ("test_dict is unchange:", test_dict)
Output:  test_dict is unchange: {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one of the ways to do it:

```
from collections import *
d= {'zero':0,'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5}
o_d = OrderedDict(d)
    
#getting key and values of first and last element in the dictionary
last_key=list(o_d.keys())[-1]
last_value=list(o_d.values())[-1]

first_key=list(o_d.keys())[0]
first_value=list(o_d.values())[0]
    
#creating new dictionary with last key:value  
first={first_key:first_value}
last={last_key:last_value}
    
#poping first and last element in the dictionary
o_d.pop(first_key)
o_d.pop(last_key)
  
o_d={**last,**o_d}
o_d={**o_d,**first}
    
print(d)
print(o_d)
```

Hope this helps!